# How to display notice or success message during the import by Convert Adapter?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

How to display notice or success message during the import by the Convert Adapter ?

I can only display error by

> Mage::throwException($message)

.
Class responsible for this is **Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Convert_Profile_Run**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento actually have some kind a session message stack. (Something quite similar to the message bags you can find, for example on Symphony).

Those are quite easy to use, just get the session associated to the area you are in and use on of the functions `addError`, `addWarning`, `addNotice` or `addSuccess`.

Since you are on the data flow module, the session you are looking to is `dataflow/session`. Take care to get this model via a singleton otherwise, you will end up with odd multiple sessions.

```
Mage::getSingleton('dataflow/session')->addSuccess($this->__('This will add a success message'));
```

The other are :

```
Mage::getSingleton('dataflow/session')->addNotice($this->__('This a notice'));
Mage::getSingleton('dataflow/session')->addWarning($this->__('That a warning'));
Mage::getSingleton('dataflow/session')->addError($this->__('And finally an error'));
```

And the reason you actually get an error message when you throw an exception, is because somewhere on Magento core, there is a

```
try {
    // the code or class instantiation on which you throw your exception happens here
} catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
    Mage::getSingleton('dataflow/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: It's not working. I want to try throw/display manually success message during the import/export process by dataflow adapter. Propably there is in Mage_Dataflow_Model_Convert_Adapter_Io Class

Comment: @MichałWejwoda quite odd, it should work, unless they have a specific Session of the Dataflow. Let me check that and if I found something I will update the answer and notify you.

Comment: @MichałWejwoda Indeed, they have a specific session for that, it is `dataflow/session` please refer to the updated answer